# Use a separate local html file while creating a SES email template

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-ses

I am trying to add an email template to aws ses through CLI. As per the documentation, I should be using a JSON file to define the template and them upload it using the `aws ses create-template --cli-input-json file://{file-path}` command.

Now the html part of my template is way to big and I have wrote a separate file for it. I dont want to write the whole html in the `HtmlPart` key of the template json file.

For that, I have done the following in the template json:

```json
{
  "Template": {
    "TemplateName": "some_template_name",
    "SubjectPart": "Random test subject",
    "TextPart": "file://./template.txt",
    "HtmlPart": "file://./template.html"
  }
}
```

My directory structure is:

```
/template
  - template.json
  - template.html
  - template.txt
```

Now the html file works perfectly on the browser independently. The template is uploaded perfectly with the following code:

```
aws ses create-template --cli-input-json file://./template.json
```

The mail I am receiving has content as

```
file://./template.html
```

**What do I do so that the content of `template.html` is uploaded to ses instead of the string `"file://./template.html"`**

Note: I have also tried setting `"HtmlPart": "./template.html"` and it gives a similar result and shows `./template.html` as the email content.